# How does this work with only overload functions?

Tags: typescript

If i comment out the 2 overload signatures, i can't pass any parameter that satisfies my generic method.

```
class Example {
    test(...strArray: string[]):(a:string)=>void;
    test(strArray: string[]):(a:string)=>void;
    test<T extends Array<T>>(strArray: T){
        alert(strArray.length.toString());
        return (a:T)=>{console.log(a)};
    }
}

new Example().test(["hl", "soda", "matcha"]);
```

```
class Example {
    //test(...strArray: string[]):(a:string)=>void;
    //test(strArray: string[]):(a:string)=>void;
    test<T extends Array<T>>(strArray: T){
        alert(strArray.length.toString());
        return (a:T)=>{console.log(a)};
    }
}

new Example().test(["hl", "soda", "matcha"]); //Errors: it expects string and extends it to string[], that why i get string can not be assignable to string[] 3 times
```

Answer (score 0):

`T extends Array<T>` is self referential and so is recursive, it's equivalent to something like `T extends Array<T extends Array<T>>`, and also `T extends Array<T extends Array<T extends Array<T>>>`... etc. TypeScript will never be satisfied because there is no end to the recursion. The reason you get three errors is because for each string, TypeScript is actually expecting another recursive array, ad infinitum.

It seems like what you maybe want is `T extends Array<string>` instead, is there a reason you didn't do that from the start?

```
class Example {
    //test(...strArray: string[]):(a:string)=>void;
    //test(strArray: string[]):(a:string)=>void;
    test<T extends Array<string>>(strArray: T){
        alert(strArray.length.toString());
        return (a:T)=>{console.log(a)};
    }
}

new Example().test(["hl", "soda", "matcha"]); // no errors!
```

It also seems to work fine if you un-comment the function overload definitions.

Edit: as a bonus, [you can get better TypeScript introspection with a small tweak](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECiAeYC2AHEBTaBvAUNf0A9IQC7oQkAUAdLRQE4CC99YAngFzQMCWAdgHMA2gF0AlB0pgOvQWIC8APgBuAex4ATANx4CxMhUoNmrTtxL1+w8ZOmyBCleu278BkgB4AKtHTwyfBowJuwe9oqKRhYhZl5iuASJ0GAY9FTGLOzUGIIkABbUJKoAyhZWlGJiOkkE9OgkAK70fNBSHHFKWMCqfBCqGNmqAlJiAL7VBKM4UzjdvSTQSGwAYg18wNDy0HzoAO5wiKgYFYXkVEIARHkgFwA00Bd9GmB3D0hgJMB5L+I6xIkAPQA-DhZuAoAdkGh0AAmbCuaDuby+fzoQLBTJsMJlQQRKJMTFcIS0ahecQJGrJVLpaKY7JogT5QolHHDSoTGp1RrNVrSDqKLo9PoDEBDEbjBFTGZzCiLFZrYBwrY7fYIKEYGEndyUS7XV6PVTPfXvT7fC6-HD-AjAnBAA) that ensures your function returned from `test()` has the actual literal string values of the array it was called with. Just change the `strArray: T` to `strArray: [...T]`. To be honest I haven't quite worked out what effect this has exactly, I gleamed it from another StackOverflow post and haven't identified the pattern in the documentation yet.

```
class Example2 {
    test<T extends Array<string>>(strArray: [...T]){
        alert(strArray.length.toString());
        return (a:T)=>{console.log(a)};
    }
}

const myFunc2 = new Example2().test(["hl", "soda", "matcha"]);
//    ^?
// const myFunc2 = (a: ["hl", "soda", "matcha"]) => void
```

Comment: What i want is a method accepts both array and rest elements of a arbitrary type, not only string type

Comment: @ThọNguyễn can you update your original question to be more clear, then.

Comment: I searched for my question on stackoverflow and stumbled upon an answer with (strArray: any) and 2 overloads. Then i changed it to remove any and encounter this odd structure that i don't know how it works, but thank you for your answer. I have also assumed it works because of the check we set with overload functions to prevent the recursive type inference to expand forever but i'm not sure